# Ionic vs. Pure Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have just completed Ionic tutorial. Not done any real app. I am to finish a mobile app in a short period of time. If I go with pure Cordova would I be able to finish creating the app in lesser time than if go with Ionic?
What am I going to lose if I use pure Cordova (html+js+css) over Cordova with Ionic?

Answer (score 2):

Ionic essentially provides the UI layer, i.e. HTML/JS/CSS to emulate the platform-specific UI controls on Android or iOS.
So it sits on top of Cordova and wraps it.
It's Typescript-based, whereas Cordova itself uses plain JS, so [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) provides Typescript wrappers for many popular Cordova plugins so you write all your app code in Typescript.

However, there are other UI frameworks you can use with Cordova, for example [Framework7](https://framework7.io/).
This is based on plain JS (rather than Typescript) and is similar to jQuery in its JS API.

Note that Ionic is moving away from Cordova with its own replacement native mobile runtime: [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Choosing tech to work with highly depends on the project you're working.

Because each and everyone of this Lang's have advantage and disadvantage.

Maybe ionic will shine more the project you want to work on now, but because of time you're choosing Cordova.

**Choose Lang's according to the nature of project.**